# copying a char array with and without a pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

can someone help me here. I am experimenting on copying an array of characters using char array (in the first case) and using a pointer(in the second case) I understand why I need a temp[i]='\0' immediately after the while loop in the first case but I dont understand why I dont need it after the while loop in second case.

```
               1st case:
char source[50] = "Hello World";
char temp[50];
int i = 0;

    while (source[i] != '\0')
    {
        temp[i] = source[i];
        i++;
    }
    temp[i]='\0';
    cout << temp;

                  2nd Case:

char source[50] = "Hello World";
char *temp=source;
int i = 0;

while (source[i] != '\0')
{
    temp[i] = source[i];
    i++;
 }
cout << temp;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167906/discussion-on-question-by-marionaglenni-copying-a-char-array-with-and-without-a).

Answer (score 2):

> I understand why I need a temp[i]='\0' immediately after the while loop in the first case

Right, because you stopped the loop just before copying the `'\0'`, so you have to do so artificially at the end.

> I dont understand why I dont need it after the while loop in second case.

Because `temp` is not a new array — it's just a pointer to the elements of the old one. Every single assignment in that loop is like `x = x`: you're just overwriting an array with itself.

You don't need to add a `'\0'` because the source array *is* the destination array, so it's already there.

In logical terms, the code in the second case achieves nothing.

Comment: Race in Orbit. I have thought about what you just said and I understand perfectly. A million thanks. I also misunderstood a lot of things. Correct me again if I am wrong but I think temp is pointing to the elements of source on the stack itself. It is only when we use the new operator that a pointer points to elements on the heap